# Браузер загружает шрифт, но не отображает его. Не могу отобразить шрифты Shopify

Tags: css, шрифты, sass

Пробую подключить свои шрифты в Shopify, пока четно. Шрифт подключается, то есть браузер его видит. Это видно в devtools Хрома и Мозиллы. (Когда указываешь неверный путь, он его уже не видит. Т.е проблемы с подключением нет.) Однако шрифт не отображается. Понять не могу почему. Стили в Shopify в SASS - скорее всего есть какая то особеннось которую я не знаю.

```
    @font-face {
      font-family: BebasNeue;
      src: url('./BebasNeue-Regular.otf') format('opentype'),
           url('./BebasNeue-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
        
      font-style: normal; 
    }
    
    h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 {
        font-family: BebasNeue, sans-serif !important;
    }
```

Данный css подключаю в конец theme.scss.liquid

Answer (score 0):

Решение банальное. Загруженный шрифт просто не поддерживает кириллицу, поэтому и не отображался.